# javascript attributes store this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is something like the following possible?

```
var obj = {
    data:'some data',
    init:function(){
        console.log(this.data);
        console.log(obj.data);
    }
}
obj.init();
```

Here, `console.log(this.data)` and `console.log(obj.data)` both return the same value.

Is it possible to store `this` in some variable like I stored `'some data'` in `data`?

Let's say somehow we store `this` in `$this`. Then, `console.log($this.data)` should work like `console.log(this.data)`.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but not in a single step. What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: (Note the emphasis on "*actually*"...)

Comment: @MattBall , because this i can't use inside a callback function, but if i store this in first place, i think i'll be able to call inside the callback function as well as in direct methods...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you'd want to do what you're asking, but yes you can do it:

```
var obj = {
    data:'some data',
    init:function(){
        this.self = this;
        console.log(this.data);
        console.log(obj.data);
        console.log(this.self);
    }
}
obj.init();
```

If you explain why you're trying to do this, we can probably advise more appropriately and there is little reason to save the value of `this` in an instance variable since the value of `this` is already required in order to retrieve instance variables.

Comment: i dont want to store this inside any function, i want to store this as data. so that i can call it inside any function or method.

Comment: because this i can't use inside a callback function, but if i store this in first place, i think i'll be able to call inside the callback function as well as in direct methods...

Comment: @hamidraza - please show us the whole code where you want to use the `this` value you stored.  In your example, `this` is already stored in the `obj` variable so it can be used from there.  `obj.data` will reference the data you stored.

Comment: the code i am expecting will be something like this...
 `var obj = {
  data:'some data',
  $this:this,
  init:function(){
   console.log(this.data);
   console.log(obj.data);
   console.log($this.data);
  }
 }
 obj.init();`

Comment: @hamidraza - You cannot use `this` in a static declaration like you've proposed because `this` is not set to the object at that point.  and there would be no point because `obj` already contains that value.  It also wouldn't do you any good because you'd need the value of `this` already just to access it.

Answer (score 1):

As in... assignment?

```
var $this = this;
```

EDIT: If you mean something like this:

```
var obj = {
    selfReference: this
};
```

Then no, that's not possible. You'd have to assign it afterwards:

```
var obj = {};
obj.selfReference = obj;
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do that in the first place, though.

Comment: you are saying we can write code like this :

`var obj = {
    var $this = this;
    data:'some data',
    init:function(){
        console.log(this.data);
        console.log(obj.data);
        console.log($this.data);
    }
}
obj.init();`
.... this will not work

Comment: @hamidraza: No, you can't do that. The line belongs inside the function, and now I'm just confused. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the way can store 'some data' in 'data', is it possible to store 'this' in '$this' ?

Comment: @hamidraza: Not in *exactly* the same way, but why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: because this i can't use inside a callback function, but if i store this in first place, i think i'll be able to call inside the callback function as well as in direct methods...

Comment: @hamidraza: Store it as a regular variable inside the method containing the callback function. Think about it; if you want to keep a reference to an object, what good will putting it inside the object do if you need it to get a reference to the object in the first place?

Comment: Yes I know i can do that, But just wanted to know if something like this is possible, if not possible its not a big problem...

Answer (score 1):

Storing `this` is done quite frequently in Javascript to avoid problems with function scope. Often the variable used to store `this` is called `that` as in:

`var that = this`

You can also set the this object of the function you are calling by using

```
myFunction.call(myCustomThisReference, param1, param2)
```

or

```
myFunction.apply(myCustomThisReference, [param1,param2]
```

See [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more details